# Weird undefined error on server

Tags: meteor

I have the following meteor method

```
hasNoPendingPayments: function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    console.log(userId); <---------------------- correctly logs userId
    var user   = Users.findOne({_id: userId }, { fields: { services: 0 } });
    console.log(user); <-------------------------- logs 'undefined'
    return hasNoPendingPayments(user);
  },
```

This private helper I call from the above

```
hasNoPendingPayments = function(user) {
  // console.log('hasNoPendingPayments ');
  // console.log(user);
  var payments = Payments.find({ userId: user._id, status: {
    $in: [Payments.States.PENDING, Payments.States.PROCESSING]}
  });

  return payments.count() === 0;
};
```

And I call it from the client here

```
Template.payments.created = function() {
  this.hasNoPendingPayments      = new ReactiveVar(false);v
};

Template.payments.rendered = function () {
  Session.set('showPaymentRequestForm', false);

  var self = this;
  Meteor.call('hasNoPendingPayments', function(error, result) {
    if (result === true) { self.hasNoPendingPayments.set(true); }
  });
  ...
```

However, I get an undefined error on the server when I load the template initially (I marked where in code). Although, when I try call the same query on the client with the same userId, i correctly gets the user record

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Are we sure that the user has logged in at the time when the `payments` template is rendered? If he/she is in the process of logging in, then you could get this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Template.payments.rendered = function () {
  Session.set('showPaymentRequestForm', false);

  var self = this;
if(Meteor.userId()){
  Meteor.call('hasNoPendingPayments', function(error, result) {
    if (result === true) { self.hasNoPendingPayments.set(true); }
  });
}else{
console.log("Seems like user its not logged in at the moment")
}
```

Maybe when you make the Meteor.call, the data its not ready

Also just to be sure, when you run `Users.findOne({_id: userId }, { fields: { services: 0 } });` on console.log what you get?

Maybe the find is wrong or have some typo

**update**

```
Router.map(function() 
    {
    this.route('payments', 
        {
        action: function() 
            {
            if (Meteor.userId())
                this.render();
            } else{
                this.render('login') // we send the user to login Template
         }
        }
    }
```

or `waitOn`

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('payments', {
    path: '/payments',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe("userData"); //here we render template until the subscribe its ready
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're right, initially I am not logged in. The findOne returns Object {_id: "Co5bMySeaqySgDP6h", emails: Array[1], profile: Object, earnings: Object}

Comment: Well use the if(Meteor.userId()){}, because you are calling that Method when the template its rendered, lets make sure the Meteor.call just run when we have a user logged

Comment: It does, so that's the problem. What is the best way to make sure that Meteor.user() is ready when rendering a template using Iron-router?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor stores all the user records in `Meteor.users` collection

so try `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId }....)`

Instead of `Users.findOne({_id: userId }, { fields: { services: 0 } });`

in your server method

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I store the collection handle in a global variable like this Users = Meteor.users; This is not possible i presume?